# TYPO3 Backend - Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function

Tags: requirejs, typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x

I have the same problem described here:
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/67446
But with TYPO3 8 LTS.

If I remove my `<f:be.container>` and add the JavaScript and CSS by hand, I get that the JumpUrl is missing for the `<f:be.menu.actionMenu>`.

I have tried to remove the `<f:be.buttons.csh/>` and `<f:be.menus.actionMenu>` to see if the `<f:be.xyx>` duplet was causing the problem, but that isn't the case either.

Any hints would be helpfull

my `Partials/Header.html`

```
<div class="module-docheader t3js-module-docheader" style="height: auto;">
    <div class="module-docheader-bar module-docheader-bar-navigation t3js-module-docheader-bar t3js-module-docheader-bar-navigation" style="height: auto;">
        <div class="module-docheader-bar-column-left">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                    <f:be.buttons.csh/>
                    <f:be.menus.actionMenu additionalAttributes="{class: 'form-control t3-js-jumpMenuBox'}">
                        <f:be.menus.actionMenuItem label="Link 1" controller="BackendModule" action="index"/>
                        <f:be.menus.actionMenuItem label="Link 2" controller="BackendModule" action="show"/>
                    </f:be.menus.actionMenu>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my `Templates/Index.html`

```
<f:be.container
        includeCssFiles="{
            2: '{f:uri.resource(path:\'Css/backendModule.min.css\')}'
        }"
        includeJsFiles="{
            0: '{f:uri.resource(path:\'Contrib/Angular/angular.min.js\')}',
            1: '{f:uri.resource(path:\'JavaScript/backendModule.min.js\')}'
        }">
    <div class="typo3-fullDoc">
        <f:render partial="Header" />
        <div id="typo3-docbody">
            <div id="typo3-inner-docbody">
                <h1>This is my content</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</f:be.container>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've switched from the `<f:be:container>` to the `<f:be.pageRenderer>`, they take almost the same arguments, at least im not missing any arguments.

This means that the JavaScript JumpUrl function is missing, but I've added that manually to my template.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function jumpToUrl(URL) {
        window.location.href = URL;
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

With this my problem is solved, I don't like the fact that I have the `jumpToUrl` added manually, but for now I can accept till I find a better way.